# Spark/ Scala- Faster Way to Load Dataframe in Hive Table

Tags: scala, apache-spark, hive

I have a data frame which I intend to write as a Hive partitioned table. The code I use to that end is

```
for(i <- 0 until 10)
{
  myDf = hiveContext.sql("select * from srcTable where col = "+i)
  myDf.write.mode("append").format("parquet")
        .partitionBy("period_id").saveAsTable("myTable")
}
```

`myDf` will contain a different set of data in every iteration (I have just shown an oversimplified way of how I get values in `myDf`)

The `myDf.write` takes about 5 minutes to load 120,000 rows of data. Is there any way I could further reduce the time taken to write all this data?

Answer (score 0):

first, why do you iterate and not just lead/save all data at once? Second, I could imagine that with your code, you write too many (small) files, you could check that on the filesystem. Normally I repartition my dataframe according to the same column which I use as partition-column of the `DataFrameWriter`, like this I get only 1 file per partition (as long as it isn't too large, otherwise HDFS will automatically split the file):

```
val cols = (0 until 10)

hiveContext.table("srcTable")
  .where($"col".isin(cols:_*))
  .repartition($"period_id")
  .write
  .format("parquet")
  .partitionBy("period_id")
  .saveAsTable("myTable")
```

Other than that, it's always a good idea to like into SparkUI and check whether the number of tasks is in a reasonable relation with the number of executors/cores.

Comment: The loop is there because many other tasks other than what I showed are performed using it. Plus the `select * from srcTable where col = ` part is quite complex with a lot of joins from other dataframes. Even if I didn't use the iteration, the time here is consumed by the way I write the dataframe in the table. I figured this way out after a lot of searching but I still wanted to know if there was any way I could speed it up even more. I'm a bit new to Spark so I'm gonna have to look up the executors/ core part.